# Assumption in Proof that Every $p$-Group is Solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, p-groups, solvable-groups

I found this proof [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/every-p-group-is-solvable)

[image]

My question is with fourth bullet point. It says,

> Note that $G_1 = Z(G)$ is normal in $G$. . . .So the quotient group $G/G_1$ is defined and furthermore $|G/G_1| = |G|\; / \; |G_1| = \frac{p^k}{p}.$

I know that $G_1 = Z(G)$ is not trivial, but how do we know that $|Z(G)| = p$ and not, say, $p^2$?

Comment: We don't, the author is mistaken at that point. Also later, the text says "$G_2$ subgroup of $G$ containing $G_1$ that is isomorphic to $Z(G/G_1)$" : that's not what it should say, but rather something like $G_2$ is the inverse image of $Z(G/G_1)$ in $G$

Comment: So $G_2$ would be $G \;$ "without" $G_1$, since $G_1$ gets mapped to $e$ by $\pi ^{-1}$, where $\pi$ is the quotient map?